# How to reduce ext4 rootlv on centos 6

Tags: lvm, grub, mbr, lvreduce

Is there a way to perform a safe reduce in rootlv at rescue mode? Most of the internet's explanations tells, basically, that it can be done using the following steps sequence:

vgchange;
fsck;
resize2fs;
lvreduce;
reboot

I tried it a several times; but all I get when system pass through POST is the same error:

FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE

Is that a way to do that safely?

Comment: Well, for one thing, use `lvreduce -r`, that avoids the risk of accidentally passing different sizes to `resize2fs` and `lvreduce`. Other than that, how are you booting this system? Odd you'd get a POST error...

Comment: @derobert, I reboot the virtual machine where I'm testing the steps, and then I get the mencioned error.

Comment: To be clear, you're resizing a logical volume inside the VM, not outside the VM, correct? That is, not the backing device storing the entire VM image?

Comment: @derobert, exactly, I'm trying to reduce rootlv of a system installed in a virtualbox VM, a lab; NOT THE DISK COUNTAINING the VM's files.

Comment: Ok, those steps would work on a KVM/Debian setup, at least if done from the initramfs (can't resize a mounted partition). I'm pretty sure they'd work with KVM/CentOS as well, though I haven't done that. I'd guess it's something different with the way VirtualBox is booting from the image. I suggest editing the details from these comments in, and hopefully someone who has dealt with CentOS on VirtualBox will stop by.

Comment: Please also give the full commands you're running, so someone can check for mistakes in them.

Comment: @dagobert, I figured out what I was doing wrong! I'll explain on the answer. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps I was doing were right at all. The problem was the way I was booting my system. BIOS found CentOS media, then installation menu has been shown to me. I was trying to boot choosing option "boot from hard drive" and after that I have received the error described before.

I repeated the steps again, but from this time I ejected CentOS' media *before reboot*. Bingo! It worked very well.

So, for help another person that eventually needs to reduce rootlv, here's howto:

1. Boot from a CentOS media (option rescue mode. **Don't mount your system when asked by the wizard**);
2. Activate rootvg (`vgchange -ay rootvg`. In case of you don't know vg's name, type `vgs` command)
3. Run fsck on rootlv (for example: `fsck -f /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv`. In case of you don't know lv's name, type `lvs` command)
4. Run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv 10G` (taking on the size you'd like your LV to stay — 10 GB, for example, when you reduce 15 GB to 10 GB)
5. Run `lvreduce -L 10 GB /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootlv` (the step 4 can be skipped if you use `-r` parameter here)
6. Reboot the machine.

Comment: BTW: `lvreduce -r` actually does steps 3 and 4, not just 4.